# Oauth 2.0 - Single resource server but multiple client applications

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, oauth-2.0, spring-security-oauth2

Greeting,

I wanted to ask if following is a valid use case for Oauth 2.0:

1. Authorization server (separate)
2. Single (or multiple) resource servers
3. Multiple client applications accessing same resource server.

[image: Diagram for scenario in question]

If this is a valid use case, how can we configure multiple clients with Authorization server. Not able to configure using application.properties ( application.yml).

```
security.oauth2.client.client-id=dummy
security.oauth2.client.client-secret=password
```

or

```
security:
  oauth2:
    resource:
      token-info-uri: http://localhost:8080/oauth/check_token
    client:
      client-id: dummy
      client-secret: password
```

What is the correct configuration for multiple client application in such scenarios?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

so if you have multiple client, you can register client detail in AuthorizationServer by extend `AuthorizationServerConfigurerAdapter`

the following is the example how you register client detail in memory:

```
@EnableAuthorizationServer
@Configuration
public class AuthServerConfig extends AuthorizationServerConfigurerAdapter {
    private final AuthenticationManager authenticationManager;

    @Autowired
    public AuthServerConfig(AuthenticationManager authenticationManager) {
        this.authenticationManager = authenticationManager;
    }

    @Override
    public void configure(ClientDetailsServiceConfigurer clients) throws Exception {
        clients.inMemory()
                .withClient("egen")
                .secret("{noop}egensecret")
                .authorizedGrantTypes("authorization_code","refresh_token","password")
                .scopes("food_read","food_write")
            .and()
                .withClient("oauthclient")
                .secret("{noop}oauthclient-secret")
                .authorizedGrantTypes("client_credentials", "refresh_token")
                .authorities("ROLE_USER", "ROLE_OPERATOR")
                .scopes("food_read");
    }
///more code
}
```

for more detail, you can take a look at my github repo:

https://github.com/Dovchiproeng/spring-cloud-security-oauth2-poc/blob/master/spring-cloud-secure-auth-server/src/main/java/com/egen/springcloudsecureauthserver/config/AuthServerConfig.java

Comment: Thanks for code snippet. There are two places we need to configure: 1. Authorization server 2. Resource server. This one will solve authorization server config (I guess we can't configure using application.properties). For part 2. Resource server there is no option to do it in application.properties or using RemoteTokenServices. Calling set client on tokenService multiple times will just over write it. Can you please add answer for part 2 in your answer as well. Thanks

Comment: for part2, you will just need to use `@EnabledResourceServer` and using remoteTokenServices to check token with the checkTokenUrl from Authorization Server. for SetClientId and SetSecret in RemoteTokenServices is just a Basic Auth for the checkToken endpoint in case some Authorization Server need it. However the access token requested by those 3 client application's clientId and secret, will return you different scope and authorities. --continue in next comment

Comment: which you can use @PreAuthroized in resources server if you want to limit the authorities of some client app. By default they should be able to access your resources server for just authentication.