# Register multiple clients in Okta

Tags: oauth-2.0, oauth, azure-api-management, okta

I have an API exposed through Azure APIM and would like to share the API with multiple clients. The clients' applications would authenticate from Okta and use the API.

I have created an Application in Okta, which provides just 1 Client Id and Secret. I don't want to share the same client credentials with different clients. How can I register multiple clients and share my API?

I don't want to register separate Apps on Okta and duplicate APIs on Azure APIM (as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58858495/azure-apim-oauth-2-0-with-multiple-clients)) every time a new client wants to use my API.

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53716247/oauth-2-0-single-resource-server-but-multiple-client-applications) question describes my problem but it is not specific to Okta OAuth.

I am also not sure if my approach is correct or do I need to follow some other approach in order to achieve this. Please help.

Thanks,

Comment: You can refer to [Custom OAuth 2.0 Authorization Server](https://developer.okta.com/docs/guides/customize-authz-server/main/). You can also ask the same question on [Okta Forum](https://devforum.okta.com/) or [Auth0 Support](https://support.auth0.com/)

Comment: @DeepDave-MT, thanks for your response. I have asked the same question on Okta forum. Will update here once I am able to resolve my problem.

Comment: @Abdullah did you find an answer to this question?

Comment: @Artur, yes I found the answer from our internal team which handles Okta. I have added it as the accepted answer, you can upvote it if you find it useful. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create an Okta Application and add a Consumer in Okta for each client who needs access. Each Consumer gets an ID and Secret. The Consumer IDs and Scopes are declared in Azure APIM Policies (xml) attached to the API.

Edited:
I think our Okta team referred to Client as 'Consumer'. The Policy XML in APIM validates the client-id (cid) claim of incoming requests. Following xml might help:

```
<validate-jwt header-name="Authorization" failed-validation-httpcode="{{Error Code}}" failed-validation-error-message="{{Error Message}}">
    <openid-config url="{{Metadata URL}}" />
    <required-claims>
        <claim name="cid" match="any">
            <value>{{Client ID 1}}</value>
            <value>{{Client ID 2}}</value>
        </claim>
        <claim name="aud" match="any">
            <value>{{Audience}}</value>
        </claim>
        <claim name="scp" match="any">
            <value>{{Scope}}</value>
        </claim>
        <claim name="iss" match="any">
            <value>{{Issuer}}</value>
        </claim>
    </required-claims>
</validate-jwt>
```

Comment: What do you mean by "consumer"?

Comment: @Artur, I think our Okta team referred to Client as 'Consumer'.

Comment: Ok, I think I got it. So I need to create an application for the protected resource + a client (that is essentially an application too in Okta) for each client app that wants to access the protected resource. Then need to configure scopes and policies to ensure only client apps can request scopes required by the protected resource. Otherwise, any okta app will be able to use its client/secret pair to get access_token and authenticate against the protected resource even if they were created for a different purpose. @Abdullah, thanks for the direction!

Answer (score 1):

The major question here: is your API designed to be machine-to-machine, which require `client_credentials` flow, or is it going to have a person context, in which case, you can have just one application in Okta with multiple Okta users assigned to it?

In the first case, there is no other way around, you will have to have multiple Okta Apps created

Comment: Thanks for your answer. The API has to be machine-to-machine, so I'll have to use the client-credentials flow.